# How to download steam games and install it on a computer offline?

Tags: games, steam

I am looking for a way to download steam free to play games on one computer which is connected to the internet, but then how to move those files to another computer which is offline. (lan-ed)

Answer (score 0):

easiest Way would be to link the Archive to the other Computer in Steam Options so you dont have to move Files, Performance may vary though. Or the other Way around, install the Archive from the Online-Machine directly on the Offline one by changing the Archive Folder in Steam Options.